# Python, attemping to use multiple accumulator variables

Tags: python

I'm creating a very crude 'stock trading' program. This program loads in a file of data about stock prices and then creates a moving average of a length of 20 days in the data that moves in increments of one day. The program must then make a decision whether to buy or sell stocks based on the price. I can't get my program to properly keep track of the stocks I've bought/sold and how much money I have left. I've only included the relevant parts of my program.

```
netWorth = 1000
stocks = 0

def moving_average():
    for day in range(1, len(closeColum)):
        if day < 21:
            continue
        twenty_days = sum(closeColum[(day-20):day]) 
        running_avg = twenty_days/20
        if closeColum[day] < running_avg:
            buyFunction(day, closeColum)
        if closeColum[day] > running_avg:
            sellFunction(day, closeColum)
        else:
            continue

        print(stocks)

def buyFunction(day, closeColum):
    netWorth1 = netWorth
    stocks1 = stocks
    while netWorth1 > 0: 
        netWorth1 = netWorth1 - closeColum[day] 
        stocks1 += 1
    return(stocks1, netWorth1)


def sellFunction(day, closeColum):
    stocks2 = stocks
    netWorth2 = netWorth
    while stocks2 > 0: 
        netWorth2 = netWorth2 + closeColum[day] 
        stocks2 -= 1
    return(stocks2, netWorth2)
```

Comment: Hello, can you check your identation?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to keep track of the stocks purchased and the amount of money I have ("netWorth") over the loop of all the "days" that there is data for.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
stocks2 = stocks
```

you're making a copy of `stocks` that lives separately. Then when you modify it:

```
stocks2 -= 1
```

this has no effect on the `stocks` variable.

```
return(stocks2, netWorth2)
```

also does not affect `stocks`, and since you're not using that return value anywhere in `moving_average` it's especially useless.

What you need to do is to modify the value of the actual `stocks` variable. Presumably this caused an error because you can't normally modify a global variable from within a function unless you specially ask to do so like so:

```
def buyFunction(day, closeColum):
    global stocks
    ...
```

Now you can modify the global variable directly with statements such as `stocks += 1`. The same needs to be done for `netWorth`.

Alternatively, you could wrap these functions inside a class, which is generally better practice than using global variables (for reasons such as the fix we just had to make). But if your script is simple and you're still getting the hang of Python, don't worry about that yet.